# What is the best way to save a numpy poly1d object to a file?

Tags: python, numpy, export, curve-fitting, polynomials

I am fitting `x` and `y` values with a 1D polynomial, using the `poly1d` `numpy` function:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 8, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)
p = np.poly1d(z)
```

What is the best way to export the poly1d object `p` to a file, so that I can access it later using another Python script?

I know that I can simply export the coefficients to a text file, but by doing so, I am losing part of the information contained in `p`, such as the order of the polynomial (*e.g.* for the above example, typing `p.order` returns 8).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need all the info required to initialise `p` later and it seems `z` suffices.

Comment: Duh! Of course! I should have thought of this in the first place! I will export z instead of p, then. Thanks a lot for your answer, Reti43!

Answer (score 0):

As brought up by Reti43 in the comment section, a simple way to handle this is simply to export `z` and to (re)initialize `p` when needed.